# Is is acceptable to use an internal email as references?

Tags: references

I received an email from a very senior person at my company complementing my work.

I live in a country, in which written references are the norm. They are normally attached to the application.

I'm wondering whether attaching this email to my application (next to formal references) would be ok.

For it to make sense, I would need to keep the email address from which I received the email visible and add a comment who the person is.

Is that acceptable?

The thing is due to a political conflict at the end of my stay at the company my written references from the company aren't very good. However, this email actually came from a much more senior stakeholder than my "formal" references.

My goal is obvious I think: growing my chances to get a job.

Comment: Why don't you ask this person if they would be willing to write a formal reference for you?

Answer (score 8):

> Is that acceptable?

NO, unless you ask him for his permission. Why? Because the company you're applying to might use his references to contact him and ask him about you. And if he wasn't informed about that before (by you), he might be surprised or annoyed.

The best thing to do is ask him to write a reference letter for you, or at least ask him if you can use his email as a reference.

Comment: Not only that he might be surprised or annoyed, depending on the jusrisdiction it might even be deemed illegal.